# SQL Server select rows where column of type image contains a substring

Tags: sql-server, image, sql-server-2016

Have a table where two columns of type `image`. These contain XML formatted messages. Some turn out to be invalid XML. I would like to find all records where either of the 2 columns contain '&' that isn't part of `'&amp;'`. Is this possible?

For example:

```
select * 
from maxinterrormsg 
where msgdata like '%&CAP%' 
   or intmsgdata like '%&CAP%'
```

Except of course this does not work.

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). Also: `image` is a **binary** datatype - not very well suited to store **textual data** like an XML document .....

Comment: If you want to store XML, then use the `xml` datatype. As @marc_s mentions, `image` is deprecated, and has been since 2005.

Comment: legacy db situation